# XamDataGrid Binding problem

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to bind a cell of a XamDataGrid using ComboBox control through a collection's(CurrentEntity.INVTransactions) property(BatchList) but it does not work.
I'm using mvvm pattern.In my code "BatchId" and "BatchList" are the properties of CurrentEntity.INVTransactions collection.

would you please tell me why the comboBox of the xamDataGrid doesn't display the BatchList?

sample code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PDCL.ERP.Modules.Inventory.Views.RequisitionList.RequisitionInfoUserControl"
            ...>    
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Header="Details" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,5,0">
        <Grid>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid Margin="2"  DataSource="{Binding CurrentEntity.INVTransactions}" x:Name="requisitionDeailsGrid" InitializeRecord="requisitionDeailsGrid_InitializeRecord">                   
                <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                    <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings HighlightAlternateRecords="True" 
                                      AutoGenerateFields="False" 
                                      AllowAddNew="True" 
                                      AddNewRecordLocation="OnBottom" 
                                      AutoFitMode="Always"
                                      SupportDataErrorInfo="RecordsAndCells"
                                      DataErrorDisplayMode="ErrorIcon"
                                      />
                </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout>
                        <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                            <igDP:Field Name="Remarks" Label="Remarks" Width="Auto">
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="True" AllowResize="True"/>
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>                               
                            <igDP:Field Name="BatchId" Label="Batch" Width="Auto">
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>                                        
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                        <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">                                                    
                                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding INVTransactions.BatchList, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}, AncestorLevel=1}}" />                                                    
                                                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="BatchName" />
                                                <Setter Property="ValuePath" Value="BatchId" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>

                                    </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>
                            <igDP:Field Name="Qty" Label="Qty Supplied" Width="Auto">
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="True" AllowResize="True"/>
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>
                        </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout>
                </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid>
            </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    </UserControl>
```

The output window shows the error "BindingExpression path error: 'INVTransactions' property not found on 'object' ''XamDataGrid' (Name='requisitionDeailsGrid')'. BindingExpression:Path=INVTransactions.BatchList; DataItem='XamDataGrid' (Name='requisitionDeailsGrid'); target element is 'XamComboEditor' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')"

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the Item to the relative source of the Xamdatagrid, XamDataGrid does not have a INVTransactions Property, I think you are actually looking for the datasource which is bound to the INVTranactions property already so try changing your binding to.

```
{Binding DataSource.BatchList, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}, AncestorLevel=1}}
```

Comment: Bob vale,I had solved the prob but forget to update the answer.Anyway thanks for your try.